# WebSocketSharp cannot catch exceptions

Tags: c#, sockets, exception, websocket

I am having trouble catching and handling exceptions thrown by websocketsharp

When I connect to the server with the client, and I close the client just by ALT+F4 or X button, the server receives the exception of connection forcibly closed.

Even though, these exceptions won't crash the program, this will cause the console to be spammed by those exceptions, important messages and logs will be pushed down and nothing can be read (there is a lot of clients).

This is the exception:

```
7/28/2021 6:41:56 AM|Fatal|<>c__DisplayClass71_0.<receiveRequest>b__0:0|WebSocketSharp.WebSocketException: An exception has occurred while reading an HTTP request/response.
                            ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
                            ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
                              --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                              at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Span`1 buffer)
                              at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.ReadByte()
                              at WebSocketSharp.HttpBase.readHeaders(Stream stream, Int32 maxLength)
                              at WebSocketSharp.HttpBase.Read[T](Stream stream, Func`2 parser, Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
                              --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                              at WebSocketSharp.HttpBase.Read[T](Stream stream, Func`2 parser, Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
                              at WebSocketSharp.HttpRequest.Read(Stream stream, Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
                              at WebSocketSharp.Net.WebSockets.TcpListenerWebSocketContext..ctor(TcpClient tcpClient, String protocol, Boolean secure, ServerSslConfiguration sslConfig, Logger logger)
                              at WebSocketSharp.Ext.GetWebSocketContext(TcpClient tcpClient, String protocol, Boolean secure, ServerSslConfiguration sslConfig, Logger logger)
                              at WebSocketSharp.Server.WebSocketServer.<>c__DisplayClass71_0.<receiveRequest>b__0(Object state)
```

I tried using

```
    public class Echo : WebSocketBehavior
    {
        protected override void OnError(ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            //handle
        }
```

I tried wrapping the websocket server in a try catch

```
            try
            {
                string path = "ws://localhost:111";
                WebSocketServer wssv = new WebSocketServer(path);
                wssv.Start();
                while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Enter) { }
                wssv.Stop();
            } catch { }
```

Nothing works, the exception will the thrown and shown on the console whatever I tried.
So the question is, how do you catch those exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue disabling/hiding completely the logs output.

```
public static void Disable(this Logger logger)
{
    var field = logger.GetType().GetField("_output", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    field?.SetValue(logger, new Action<LogData, string>((d, s) => { }));
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify where exactly did you add this code? I have same issue
ERROR <>c__DisplayClass66_0.<receiveRequest>b__0:0 An exception has occurred